# Looking for a Project Ideas

Tags: bitcoin-core, development, cryptography, academic-research, project

Im a student at Sri Lanka institute of information technology and I am reading for cyber security BSc. I'm supposed to do a research project  with a group of four people within an year. We are preferring to do our research project in bitcoin domain.  We are supposed to come up with a software component which will address an existing issue in current bitcoin system. Please provide us with some opinions to come up with a valuable idea on our research project.
What is a good critical issue to address?
Any suggestions to address that issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Anjelo! This site is for technical Q&A, not for general forum posts. I'm going to close this because it's opinion based, but you might want to look at this post on reddit where someone was also looking for project ideas: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/3y8e81/need_project_ideas_im_a_15year_veteran_developer/

Comment: You can also have a look at the [open issues on Github](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues?q=is%3Aopen+sort%3Acreated-desc)